# Trouble with Prometheus relabel_configs Regex for Matching Specific URL Patterns

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I'm configuring Prometheus Operator and encountering an issue with relabel_configs in my setup. I need to match URLs based on specific conditions and relabel them accordingly, but I'm running into a regex-related error.

Here's the part of my configuration that's causing trouble:

```
          relabel_configs:
            - source_labels: [ __address__ ]
              regex: '.*(dispatcher).*'
              target_label: __param_target
              replacement: 'http://${1}/choose-your-country.html'
            - source_labels: [ __address__ ]
              regex: '.*(publish|dispatcher).*'
              target_label: __param_target
              replacement: 'https://${1}/system/health?tags=bundles,-security&httpStatus=WARN:500'
            - target_label: __address__
              replacement: 'blackbox-exporter-prometheus-blackbox-exporter:9115'
```

The goal is to:

If the url matches dispatcher or author end with the system endpoint

However I'm getting
http://blackbox-exporter-prometheus-blackbox-exporter:9115/probe such url as a target instead of expected targets

Comment: Can you explain in more details, what is your problem? Getting `http://blackbox-exporter-prometheus-blackbox-exporter:9115/probe` as target url is expected, since you're placing it there yourself by your last relabel instruction.

Comment: I want add the metric path based if the url contains dispatcher, or respectively dispatcher or publish.

Comment: Please provide an expected URL that should be scraped, if target is, for example, `asd-dispatcher-new.com:21345`

Comment: URLS data:
  targets.json: |-
    [
      {
        "labels": {
          "job": "blackbox"
        },
        "targets": [
          "dada-da-review-support-author.dada-platform.dada.de",
          "dada-dada-review-dispatcher.dada-platform.dad.de:8080"
        ]
      }
     ]  have to be come for example dada-dada-review-dispatcher.dada-platform.dad.de:8080/choose-your-country.html  and dada-da-review-support-author.dada-platform.dada.de//system/health?tags=bundles,-security&httpStatus=WARN:500

Comment: I assume those urls should be probed by blackbox exporter, since they don't really look like pages with metrics. And I assume you have blackbox exporter at address mentioned in your question and my first comment. Is that correct?

Comment: Hey there, exactly !